# How to set application independent parameters like server addedress in android

Tags: android

I need a solution  for the really common but important issue that i am thinking of.

I have created application in which  i have hard coded my  server address in  **/res/values/strings.xml** file. Suppose if my server address changes run-time due to some reasons, then i have to make changes in the file and then i have to recompile it.

So is there any way that i put my server address out of my application.. So we do not have to recomplie the application. Instead of it, it will read new server address from out side and resume its normal work...

Any type of related suggestions,links,blogs appreciated..

Comment: your talking server address, is it only IP or is it domain name that can change aswell?
If you have no idea where it is located at runtime, it is kind of hard  to get the information...

Comment: It is domain name that may be changed in case suppose server failure occurs in one domain, then i just change the server name, instead of changing the code itself.. So i want where do i put that address.. and how it should update.. So my apk will be independent of server address

Comment: So hardcode 2 adresses?
You really can't do it out of the air afaik. Else you need some kind of service at a steady provider like google to get it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by reading [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html) blog.

Which says you should use shard preferences with the activity extending **PreferenceActivity.**

Here you can set your server address and all the dynamic stuff that will change by the time. So that you will not have to recompile the apk. Just change the settings in shared preferences.

Read this important bog that all app developer wants to know it..

Answer (score 1):

While I am making apps in Android , I mostly create a Utility class e.g. Constants.java , Utils.java etc. In these classes, I put all the constant numerical and String values like this:

```
  public static String ip="74.117.153.111"; 
  public static final String LOGIN_TOKEN_URL = "http://"+ ip + "/api/getLoginToken";
  public static final String USERNAME_PARAM = "username";
  public static final String PASSWORD_FIELD_EMPTY_ERROR = "Please enter password";
  public static final int GRID_ICON_COUNT = 4;
  public static final String FACEBOOK_KEY = "16411636362877862";
```

These are some type of constants which we generally use here and there. So I put them into a different dedicated class. So now when I need their value somewhere, I get it like this:

```
params.put(Constants.USERNAME_PARAM, username);
fbRocket = new FBRocket(this, Constants.APP_NAME,Constants.FACEBOOK_KEY);
```

The benefit of this approach is that if I have to change a value later on which is being used at lot of places , then I don't have to change it everywhere. I will just change the value in Constants.java and this change will replicate in the whole app.

```
Utils.showErrorMessage(this, Constants.PASSWORD_FIELD_EMPTY_ERROR, Constants.TOAST_VISIBLE_SHORT);
```

Comment: If that is what he meant, then I clearly misunderstood him :-)